# Read any record in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create a function that would accept any PL record type as parameter? This would be useful for logging.
I played arround with LCRs before and LCR structure could be read and values extracted no matter where it came from.

Comment: Plz elaborate with some examples

Comment: Logging the record type values. Can you write a procedure that would accept any record type and read values from that record type without declaring the record type and not knowing in advance that record type structure and types contained.

Comment: I think you can't do that with records. Maybe with an object instead?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The workaround is to create a subprogram that converts a record to a string. Yes, it's laborious and verbose but sometimes PL/SQL is.

```
declare
  type foo_t is record (
   a number
  ,b varchar2(32767)
  );
 function to_str(r in foo_t) return varchar2 is
 begin
   return '((a = ' || r.a || ')(b = ' || r.b || '))';
 end;
begin
  declare
    v_foo foo_t;
  begin
    v_foo.a := 42;
    v_foo.b := 'lorem ipsum';
    dbms_output.put_line(to_str(v_foo));
  end;
end;
/
```

If you're clever enough you can write a code generator that writes all those `to_str` subprograms for you.

Comment: I guess i could do something like this then:
p_write_log ('t_record_type', l_record_type), first parameter would be name of type, and second the actual record type mapped to anydata or anytype? and then i could query dba_objects, find that type and assemble dynamic sql which does the conversion.

Comment: @user1941235 I don't think that's possible. My current understanding is that there is no "anydata/type" for records.